# Python QT NextButton action as validation

Tags: python, multithreading, qt

I want to perform some action when the next button is clicked before allowing the next page to be passed(for example run a function), when I tried doing it using connect I found that the actions of the next page are already performed(even though it is not shown, meaning some other thread is already running the next threads' action).

Is there a way to perform some action before the next button is clicked, and as a result of this action to decide if the next page is allowed or not?

I tried something like:

```
self.ui.button(QtGui.QWizard.NextButton).clicked.connect(self._check_stuff)
```

but when check stuff is called there are already threads running the next windows' actions. anyone?

Thanks!

It was suggested that I should override the validatePage which sounds like exactly what I want, but for this I have to inherit QWizard (I have tried overriding it's member but it did not work, my QWizard is loaded via code and designer such as:)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Wizard</class>
 <widget class="QWizard" name="Wizard">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>920</width>
    <height>525</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Wizard</string>
  </property>
  <property name="wizardStyle">
   <enum>QWizard::MacStyle</enum>
  </property>
  <property name="options">
   <set>QWizard::CancelButtonOnLeft</set>
  </property>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

and then in the code I do:

```
self._ui = QtUiTools.QUiLoader().load("setup_wizard.ui")
```

how can I create my specific WQizard and specify it in the code? I tried full python path package.. did not work etc..

Answer (score 1):

You can reimplement `QWizard::validateCurrentPage()`, returning `false` if the next page is not allowed.

See [QWizard::validateCurrentPage](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwizard.html#validateCurrentPage)

Comment: Right now my QWizard is loaded via configuration, is there a way to load it from configuration and reimplement the funciton? I tried creating a subclass but it crashes on initialization

Comment: If you mean that your QWizard is created with the designer, yes, you can reimplement the function. Please post some minimal code to reproduce the crash.

Comment: I've never used QUiLoader but I think that in this way you cannot sublass your QWizard. I suggest to use the uic tool (pyuic4 in pyqt) to generate the python code of your widget where you can reimplement the method. See [this](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/designer.html)